Trying to find blank cells in Range ("AH2:BF2") then delete that cell and 19 cells below and shift rows to left
As title mention "Trying to find blank cells in Range ("AH2:BF2") then delete that cell and 19 cells below and shift rows to left."
Below is what I think should work but I think I'm missing one step.
Sub tryingtodeleteblankdates()

   Dim myCell As Range
   
    For Each myCell In Range("AH2:BF2")
    
    If myCell.Value = "" Then
    ActiveWorksheet.Range(myCell, Range(myCell.Offset(19))).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    End If
    
  
 Next myCell
    
End Sub

I would appreciate any guidance. Sorry if this is duplicate I tried googling this.

Please explain what this is doing that is incorrect?

I get a Run-Time Error saying "Method "Range" of Object '_Global" Failed.
so I think the problem is here
ActiveWorksheet.Range(myCell, Range(myCell.Offset(19))).Select


Replace the two lines inside the If with myCell.Resize(20).Delete Shift:=xlShiftToLeft.

do what @BigBen states, but the error in your range is you are trying to do a range of one cell inside the outer range.  The inner range is not needed: Range(myCell, myCell.Offset(19))

That fixed it thank you two so much. Can I give kudos or something for the help?

Sorry I'm running into another issue, i think i need to go through my range in reverse cause the wrong selection is getting deleted. Could I get help adding that to my marco?

Nevermind, I think i'm just an idiot and fat finger another marco
